# Reduced bing map to lowest extent does not fit in the map area

Tags: javascript, zooming, openlayers, bing-maps

When we reduce the map size to lowest possible size by scrolling down or clicking zoom(-) sign, a square is shown which does not exactly fit in the map area on my web page.

i implemented bing map over openlayer.

cant attach image due to repo constraint on stackoverflow.

as of now my implementation looks like [current look](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/bing.html) but i want map should look like [desired look](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/bing-maps.html)

Comment: as of now my implementation looks like [link](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/bing.html) but i want map should look like [new Link](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/bing-maps.html)

Answer (score 1):

if you mean that your map is too small for the DIV area, but the DIV area itself is OK, you can tell your map what is the last zoom level you want to use by setting the map options at the map init:

```
  map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{ numZoomLevels: 5, minZoomLevel: 3, maxZoomLevel: 5 } );
```

plus/minus zoom makes only your zoom change, not the area of the map, the area stays the same within the page. so how do you want the area of the map to be affected by zooming?
the area of the map is dependent only upon the size of the DIV that the map is placed in.
this is the DIV in your first exapmle: `<div id="map" class="smallmap"></div>`. If you change the proportions of the DIV element, the area of the map is changed too.